# HVAC Furnace blowing fuses

Tags: hvac, furnace

I'm having trouble with an older Nordyne HVAC unit.

Current situation: Immediately after turning the unit on with a heat signal from the thermostat, the fuse on the control board blows. Most recently it didn't blow the fuse, however the transformer has now burned up. That's the newest problem, but I think it was a side effect of the problem, not the original problem.

I have tested all the limit switches, none are grounded and show appropriate resistance across them. However to put them out of the equation for testing I jumped them. No change. Continues to blow fuse. Replaced the board. No change other than the transformer burning up. I now have 110 coming in, but no voltage coming out.

Another note, the fuse still blows even when the signal wire for heat, white is removed from the board. And I tested the thermostat wires to see if any where grounded, none were going to ground.

Ideas? I've probably got more information I've forgotten to include.

Comment: Limit switches should not blow a fuse, anyway. Limit switches should shut the furnace down without blowing a fuse. A fuse blowing indicates that something is actually wrong.

Comment: I'll guess that the transformer has burned up as a result of overload when the fuses were replaced repeatedly. This sounds like it's going to require an in-person visit from one skilled in controls/electronics troubleshooting, but post a few pictures of the wiring diagrams (usually found on the furnace covers), the connections to the control board, and the wiring at the thermostat. We'll have a go at it. Are there any accessories connected? Humidifier, UV lamp, etc?

Comment: Yes, can you post the wiring diagram for your unit?

Comment: No accessories, limit switches were in case one was going to ground, I was told to check them, and I'll post the wiring diagram and pictures of the board when I get the chance today.